# Subject is null alwasys in Apache Shiro - Maven project

Tags: java, shiro

Returns **Null**:

```
Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
System.out.println(currentUser.getPrincipal());
```

Always it returns null, what am I missing ?
Realm is: `org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal is `null` because you don't have a user logged in.  Take a look at `Subject.isAuthenticated()` or `Subject.login()`

Comment: Yes, you are right in reference with the question, but I don't need the login to be done. Thanks anyhow I have figured out.